# MYSQL query: USING LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT jos_mod_gdwcomm.*, COUNT(jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.reportid) `num_spam` 
FROM `jos_mod_gdwcomm` 
WHERE `num_spam` > 0 
LEFT JOIN `jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam` 
ON (jos_mod_gdwcomm.id = jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.commid) 
GROUP BY jos_mod_gdwcomm.id
ORDER BY `num_spam` DESC, jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.datetime DESC
```

How can i modify this query so it only returns the rows that num_spam is greater than 0.

i tryed putting

```
WHERE `num_spam` > 0
```

In a few places but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT jos_mod_gdwcomm.*, COUNT(jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.reportid) `num_spam` 
FROM `jos_mod_gdwcomm` 
LEFT JOIN `jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam` 
ON (jos_mod_gdwcomm.id = jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.commid) 
GROUP BY jos_mod_gdwcomm.id

HAVING num_spam > 0

ORDER BY `num_spam` DESC, jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `GROUP BY jos_mod_gdwcomm.id HAVING num_spam > 0`.

Comment: Thanks it works ill approuve your answer in a few mins... wont let me just yet

Answer (score 1):

When you want to test a condition on an aggregate function, you use a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT jos_mod_gdwcomm.*, COUNT(jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.reportid) `num_spam` 
    FROM `jos_mod_gdwcomm` \
        LEFT JOIN `jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam` 
            ON (jos_mod_gdwcomm.id = jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.commid) 
    GROUP BY jos_mod_gdwcomm.id
    HAVING COUNT(jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.reportid) > 0 
    ORDER BY `num_spam` DESC, jos_mod_gdwcomm_spam.datetime DESC
```